# Tensorflow only shows one label

Tags: tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow in combination with Python 3.6 and Anaconda 1.7.0. As model I use the "faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets".

I retrained it with 8 different classes, everything works fine also the object prediction (bounding box) is right, but the problem is, that Tensorflow always shows only one label. For example I am training a detector to distinguish between several car types (SUV, Coupe, Limousine,...). So it shows for instance always the "SUV" label. 
Also strange is, that the label which is shown, is always the first one in my list. So when for example "Coupe" is written on the first place in my labelmap, the label which is predicted, is the "Coupe" label. When "SUV" stands at the first place, it is the "SUV" label.

Can it may be a configuration problem? Or maybe the weight during training is more placed on the first label?

Thank you for help!

The configuration Code of the "faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets" model:

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 8
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0002
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00002
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000002
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "C:/Users/DS/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 10000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}


train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "C:/Users/DS/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "C:/Users/DS/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 65
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "C:/Users/DS/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "C:/Users/DS/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```